# Web API Model Binder always returned null for List<string>, but works for string[]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to post a list of string (Fields) to the web api.

Post body:

```
{
...
fields: ["field1"],
...
}
```

Server side model:

```
public List<string> Fields
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(InternalFields) ? new List<string>() : InternalFields.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            InternalFields = string.Join(",", value.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToList());
        }
    }
internal string InternalFields { get; set; }
```

But the set function is never called. And another weird thing is if I changed the `list<string>` to `string[]`, it simply works!

Any reason what is happening behind the scene?

Thanks!

Comment: `Fields` and `fields` do not match

Comment: That is not what is causing the problem. I have CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver there.  The problem really is string[] works, but list<string> doesn't.

Comment: Can you post into your question the header of the request, and the definition of the method in your controller?

Comment: The "header" is nothing more than `Content-Type: application/json`. And the controller method is nothing specially either, `[ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
        [Route("analyze")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAnalysis(Model model) {}` @dnlgmzddr